# File Download Callback

Tags: javascript, download

I have a page in my site that creates a .doc file and lets the user download it. I want to be able to delete that file from the server after the user has downloaded it.

Is there any way to tell the browser to call a JavaScript callback function I wrote(so I can use ajax and delete the file), or any other way for me to know when to delete the file?

Comment: There's no way to do this reliably, AFAIK.  Your best bet is cleaning up the temp files regularly at the server.

Comment: You can do that on server too right after download is done, after the code for transmitting the file.

Comment: @Bipins how would I know when the download is done?

Comment: Do you even need to create the file (on disk)? Could you just create it in memory and stream it to the client? If not, how does the user download the doc...by clicking a link sometime after the doc has been created?

Comment: Arent you streaming the file using some code adding header as application/octet. If not then how are you sending the file? By direct link?

Comment: Im creating the file, and then giving the user a href to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there isn't. You may pass the file through a server side script (PHP, Rails, etc), which deletes it afterwards or, if your webserver runs with linux or another unix, just delete it after the download has started. On thouse platforms, the file gets deleted for real after the last process closes it's handle, so even if you delete the file while the user still downloads it, the user can continue to do so.

Comment: Sadly my server uses windows, nice Linux solution though.

Answer (score 1):

After you have streamed your file from server, you can delete them. What you are using at server side. For example in aspx, http://forums.asp.net/p/1204802/2109808.aspx

```
  private void fileDownload(string fileName, string fileUrl)
    {
        Page.Response.Clear();
        bool success = ResponseFile(Page.Request, Page.Response, fileName, fileUrl, 1024000);
        if (!success)
            Response.Write("Downloading Error!");
        else
       // you can delete here
        Page.Response.End();
    }
```